# Configuring multiple java on linux

Tags: java, linux, bugzilla

I have a linux vm which is our testing machine. as part of some initiative, I want to install some software on this vm which would require Java 6+. Currently its running java 5 which i don't want to change because of the compatibility with test environment.

I want to know who can i configure multiple JAVA on this vm.

Comment: How did you install the first one?

Comment: it was given to us pre-configure by it group. but does this matter ?

Comment: question belongs on superuser.com

Comment: i believe java 6 is backward compatible with java-5.so y can't you remove java 5 and use java 6 sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By installing the binaries to another location, and then directily referencing the file you can start using a specific binary

Instead of

`java -jar Derp.jar`

it will be

`/opt/java5/bin/java -jar Derp.jar`